# What is the best way of defining optional propTypes in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an optional propType

```
static defaultProps = {
   onSort: undefined, // undefined | () => {}
}
```

If undefined, we will check for `undefined` before the function is called.

```
_handleSort = () => {
   this.props.onSort && this.props.onSort()
}
```

So, how do I handle the propType of type `Function | undefined`. Should I check for undefined before calling the function or define a default function `() => {}`

Answer (score 10):

```
static propTypes = {
  onSort: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.func,
    PropTypes.any
  ])
}
```

Then check if `onSort` exist.

```
if (this.props.onSort) {
  //do something
}
```

OR

Define the `propTypes` like this:

```
static propTypes = {
  onSort: PropTypes.func
}
```

then have a default for `onSort` like so:

```
static defaultProps = {
   onSort: () => null
}
```

Comment: Why use PropTyes.any? The initial request was to check if the function is null or not ...

Answer (score 3):

This issue suggests defining a default function as you have indicated above: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1067

```
Cmp.defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {}
}
```

However, I am still trying to get this to work. I'd be interested if you have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
static defaultProps = {
  onSort: PropTypes.func,
}
if(this.props.onSort){
  //do something
}
```

What about this? So you're right with checking the property before calling/using it.

Comment: Or do I define a default propType, so that there is no error

Comment: What would that default type be? You will probably need to check it if its a default type, so you can leave in unassigned